# No Bootable Medium For Ubuntu VirtualBox

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

Im trying to install the latest version of Ubuntu on my VirtualBox. Here is what I've done.

1. Downloaded and converted the .7z file for Ubuntu and converted it to and ISO file
2. Created the new virtual machine with a virtual hard drive and fixed size
3. Under Settings and Storage --> Under the controllers tab I've pointed the location to the ISO image.
4. Under Settings and System --> Unchecked the floppy disk option.

When I go to run it I get the "Error: No Bootable Medium Found"
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer, the problem was the ISO file.
I downloaded a new one straight from the Ubuntu website and that solved everything

Answer (score -1):

Simply that ISO isn't boteable Media.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boot_disk

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_image